# How to efficiently load large amount of parameters in ROS?

Tags: c++, ros

What is the better way to load many parameters in ROS compared to:

```
double default_maxvel_xy = 3;
double default_maxvel_z = 1.5;
double default_maxvel_c = 1;
double default_maxacc_xy = 2;
double default_maxacc_z = 1;
double default_maxacc_c = 1;
double default_maxjerk_xy = 1;
double default_maxjerk_z = 1;
double default_maxjerk_c = 1;
n.param<double>("default_maxvel_xy", default_maxvel_xy, 3);
n.param<double>("default_maxvel_z", default_maxvel_z, 1.5);
n.param<double>("default_maxvel_c", default_maxvel_c, 1);
n.param<double>("default_maxacc_xy", default_maxacc_xy, 2);
n.param<double>("default_maxacc_z", default_maxacc_z, 1);
n.param<double>("default_maxacc_c", default_maxacc_c, 1);
n.param<double>("default_maxjerk_xy", default_maxjerk_xy, 1);
n.param<double>("default_maxjerk_z", default_maxjerk_z, 1);
n.param<double>("default_maxjerk_c", default_maxjerk_c, 1);

m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.linear.x = default_maxvel_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.linear.y = default_maxvel_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.linear.z = default_maxvel_z;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.angular.x = default_maxvel_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.angular.y = default_maxvel_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.vel_max.angular.z = default_maxvel_c;

m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.linear.x = default_maxacc_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.linear.y = default_maxacc_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.linear.z = default_maxacc_z;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.angular.x = default_maxacc_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.angular.y = default_maxacc_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.acc_max.angular.z = default_maxacc_c;

m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.linear.x = default_maxjerk_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.linear.y = default_maxjerk_xy;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.linear.z = default_maxjerk_z;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.angular.x = default_maxjerk_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.angular.y = default_maxjerk_c;
m_waypoint.max_dynamics.jerk_max.angular.z = default_maxjerk_c;
```

where it is just too many codes and prone to error.
Can I some how create a custom type in yaml and load it as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary (in Python meaning) can be loaded as map, e.g. map. List (in Python meaning) can be loaded as vector, e.g. map.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, double> parameter_map;
ros::param::get("~my_parameter_map", parameter_map);
```

Comment: It would be great, if you would add a small code example to your answer, to see how exactly it is done.